# Nifi PutSQL Timestamp/Datetime error cannot be converted error

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, update-attribute

I tried the solution suggested to remove the timestamp format conversion error by using "UpdateAttribute" processor i.e.
ConvertJSONtoSQL-> UpdateAttribute--> PutSQL

In UpdateAttribute I used

```
Property               Value
---------------        ------------------------
sql.args.4.value ->    ${sql.args.4.original:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}
```

**Log:**

> The value of the sql.args.4.value is '', which cannot be converted to
>   a timestamp   at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.setParameters(PutSQL.java:690)
>     at

Without the use of UpdateAttribute I also tried direct ConvertJSONtoSQL-> PutSQL . Log showed the same error with datetime value in quote 'Aug 14 2017 10:17:00 EDT' i.e. when we use UpdateAttribute, it just removes the value and put empty quotes but the error is not resolved.

**Note:** MySQL table has datetime datatype for those columns not sure why it errors out by trying to convert to TimeStamp. I also tried Timestamp datatype in source and target table on localhost, no luck!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my question

`sql.args.n.value -> ${sql.args.n.value:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}`.

Comment: just wanted to know if the dataflow you used is convertjsontoSQL -> updateAttribute -> putsql

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem putting Postgres in. I used queryrecord and concatenated ".000" to my date