# Trying To Solve remove the timestamp format conversion error by using "UpdateAttribute" processor i.e. ConvertJSONtoSQL-> UpdateAttribute--> PutSQL

Tags: apache-nifi

[From This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685703/nifi-putsql-timestamp-datetime-error-cannot-be-converted-error/45701012#45701012)

> Same issue but no luck in my case i'm using ConvertJsonToSql---->(Relationship--SQL,Original)---->Update Attribute(Poperty from your answer)------>PutSql.  java.sql.SQLDataException :The value of the sql.args.28.value is Mon Oct 09 23:55:23 which cannot be converted to a timestamp.

1. In Database date is storing in mysql datetime format 2017-09-11 14:26:13.
2. NiFi flow file from Capture Change Mysql is showing like Mon Sep 11 19:56:13 IST 2017.
3. JoltTransform Json also same and while converting form json to sql flow file attribute value of sql.args.27.type is 93 and sql.args.27.value is Mon Oct 09 23:38:55.

any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: there is no day of month or year  in your date: `Mon Oct 09 23:55:23`.

Comment: my table datetime column insert date like  2017-09-11 14:26:13

Comment: i'm reading mysql bin log and jolt transorm json resulting the attributes like [{
 "DiscoveredTime" : "Mon Sep 11 19:56:13 IST 2017",
 "LatestDiscoveredTime" : "Mon Oct 09 23:38:55 IST 2017"
}]

Comment: After converting json to sql flow file attributes sql.args.27.value is Mon Oct 09 23:38:55

Comment: what would be your suggestion..?

Comment: please add the details of your question into the question itself.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: where from you are getting the value like `Mon Sep 11 19:56:13 IST 2017`? can you change it to `2017-09-11 19:56:13` at source?

Comment: In source DB column (datetime type) it is stored as 2017-09-11 19:56:13 but when we retirve the data using Capture Change Mysql, we are getting Sep 11 19:56:13 IST 2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer for this 
In updateattribute processor property: sql.args.27.value and value :${sql.args.27.value:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}